# How to include path of all files when doing a directory listing

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

(In Windows/Command line) I'd like to generate a list of all files, and for each file, I also want the full path displayed.

So if you were doing a directory listing of the folder c:\users\me and it had the files a.txt, b.txt and c.txt, I'd want the following output:

```
...
c:\users\me\a.txt
c:\users\me\b.txt
c:\users\me\c.txt
...
```

Can anyone suggest a tool that does this, or do I have to actually go code this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the directory doesn't have more directories in it, using the recurse option `/s` along with bare format `/b` will show the entire path with files:

```
dir /s /b
```

if there are more folders though it will display all the files in there as well. It's a neat little workaround though.

Comment: thanks!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! that is exactly what I was looking for (I know about /s, I didn't realize /b would be useful here)

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the `for` command, although it's a little more verbose:

```
for %x in (*) do @echo %~fx
```

The `%~fx` tells `cmd` to output a full path here.

`forfiles` also works here:

```
forfiles /c "cmd /c echo @path"
```